# pass a variable from controller to model (that extends other model) codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a model that has all common database functions like:

```
class MY_Model extends CI_Model {   
    public $table;
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database();        
    }
    function insert($data) {
        $this->db->insert($this->table,$data);
        return $this->db->insert_id();
    }
    function update($where=array(),$data) {
        $this->db->update($this->table,$data,$where);
        return $this->db->affected_rows();
    }
    function delete($where=array()) {
        $this->db->delete($this->table,$where);
        return $this->db->affected_rows();
    }
    //ETC.

}
```

Now, I have a model that extends it, so in the constructor I define which table I should use like:

```
class other_model extends MY_Model { 
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();        
        $this->table = 'MY_TABLE';      
    }   
}
```

And in controller I would just do:

```
$this->load->model('other_model');  
$id_affected = $this->other_model->insert(...);
```

Now I want to take advantage of this code and reuse it, so I would like to make the table name variable and pass from controller to model this like:

```
 $this->load->model('other_model'); 
 $table_name = 'TABLE_1'
 $this->other_model->set_variable($table_name); 
 $id_affected = $this->other_model->insert(...);
```

Is there a way to do this? 
I was trying:

## Model:

```
class other_model extends MY_Model {
    var $variable;

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
         //tried here
        //$this->load->database();      
    //$this->table = $variable; 

    }

    function set_variable($variable) {
        $this->variable = $variable;

         //also tried here
        //$this->load->database();      
    //$this->table = $variable; 
    }

}
```

## Controller:

```
class test extends CI_Controller {
    function tester() {
        $this->load->model('other_model');
        $variable = 'MY_TABLE_1'
        $this->other_model->set_variable($variable); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately CI doesn't allow you to send constructor arguments when loading models. This is unfortunate since your use case is perfect for that. The table name is critical to the model and so you should not be able to initialize a model without specifying the table name. Up until the current version of CI, this isn't possible without modifying core files. If you're willing to do that, [see here](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/115681/).

Your other option, which is more dry is to add a `initialize()` method to MY_Model. The initialize method must be called before the model is usable.

```
class MY_Model {
   $this->table = NULL;

  public function initialize($tbl) {
    $this->table = $tbl;
  }

  // sample use
  public function insert($obj) {
     if ($this->table !== NULL) {
         // insert
     }
  }

}
```

Your controller code would look like this:

```
// other_model extends MY_Model
$this->load->model('other_model');
$this->other_model->initialize('user_table');
$this->other_model->insert($obj);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `__set` and `__get` magic methods and overload the model, which really isn't that hard to do, but a problem could arise if those magic methods are being using by CI_Model and you would be overwriting them...

If you want to use `set_variable`, do something like this:

```
function set_variable($var,$val){
   $this->$var=$val;
}
```

Then you can do `$this->other_model->set_variable('table','MY_TABLE_1');`

Comment: so the controller would be like : `$this->load->model('other_model'); $this->other_model->set_variable('table','MY_TABLE_1');` ?

Comment: yup.  As far as I can tell, that would get the job done.  Not tested of course.

Comment: and model `var $variable;
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function set_variable($var,$val){
   $this->$var=$val;
}}`

Comment: And where should I load the database in construct?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, no need to load the database again in child class because it's already loaded in the parent class, also I think you should change the `public $table` to `protected $table;`

```
class MY_Model extends CI_Model {   
    protected $table;
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();        
    }

    function insert($data) {
        $this->db->insert($this->table,$data);
        return $this->db->insert_id();
    }

    // ...
}

class Other_Model extends MY_Model { 
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function set_table($table){
        $this->table=$table;
    }

    function get_table(){
        return $this->table;
    }
}

class Tester extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function test() {
        $this->load->model('Other_Model');
        $this->Other_Model->set_table('MY_TABLE_1');
        $data = array(...);
        $this->Other_Model->insert($data);
    }
}
```

Comment: What error you got, I've tested this code first and then posted it.